# Login using Firebase and React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I retrieved a list from my firebase Database containing all the users. How do I check if the given user name and password exist in this list?

```
const Login = () => {

    const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
    const [password, setPassword] = useState();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        firebaseDb.child('users').on('value', snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.val() !== null)
                setUsers({
                    ...snapshot.val()
                })
            else
                setUsers({})
        })

    }, []);

        const Login = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let item = { userName, password };
    
           //How to check if item is in users
    
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form autoComplete="off" onSubmit={Login}>
            ...
);
```

The SignUp function is down below, please note that each user has a username a name and a password

```
const  signUp = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebaseDb.child('users').push(
        values,
        err => {
            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else {
                history.push("/allUsers")
                localStorage.setItem("user-info", JSON.stringify(values.name))
            }
        })
```

Comment: Ignoring the security issue regarding storing/exposing passwords & user data like this for a moment - what is the expected behaviour if a user already existed in the database?

Comment: This is not a real app, this is a technical test and it is my first time using either reactjs or firebase so I know I have weaknesses but I don't know what to do

Comment: Please answer the question I asked. What are you trying to do? If a username is found, are you trying to get the user to pick another username? Are you just trying to determine if this is the first time that user has logged in to the app?

Comment: I want to redirect the app to a different route if the user is found

Comment: I'm sorry but nothing given in your answer helped me in anything. I ended up using a totally different method to check if the user name exists.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to fetch the whole "users" node to check that. I'm not sure how your database structure looks like but usually you would have child nodes with users' UIDs as the keys and another another node which holds all the usernames taken. Then you just check if a node where username is equal to that username exists.

```
firebase.database().ref("usernames/"+"the-username").once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()){
      const userInfo = snapshot.val();
      console.log("Username taken")
      // Process and redirect
    } else {
      // username available 
    }
});
```

Make sure you add the username in that node when a new user signs up:

```
async function signUp() {
  const {user} = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  await Promise.all([
    firebase.auth().updateProfile(user.uid, {displayName: "NewUserName"}),
    firebase.database().ref(`usernames/${newUsername.toLowerCase()}`).set(true)
  ])
}
```

However anyone can bypass this and try to override existing usernames so you must add security rules to prevent that. The following rules should do it:

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
    ".read": "auth !== null &&  auth.uid === $uid",
    "username": {
      ".validate": "!root.child('usernames').child(newData.val()).exists()"
    }
  }
}
```

You cannot have multiple `.equalTo()` in realtime database. For the passwords part, I'd recommend using Firebase Authentication as that'll be safer as well. But if your requirement needs you to look up for data with given username and password (i.e. multiple equalTo), you might have to switch to Firestore.

Alternatively, you can create users using a cloud function if you don't want to maintain a separate node for usernames and use security rules.

```
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const {username, email, password} = data;
  
  // Check if username is taken from users node
  const userRef = admin.database().ref("users").orderBy("username").equalTo(username);
  if ((await userRef.once("value")).val()) return {error: "Username taken"}

  const newUser = await admin.auth().createUser({
    email,
    password,
    displayName: username
  })

  return {data: newUser.uid}
});
```

I'd recommend Firebase Auth or the Cloud functions method. If you use Firestore there's a higher chance of someone randomly spamming with login requests and it won't have any rate limiting errors such as `TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS_TRY_LATER` that Firebase Auth has.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will implement all your suggestions and will update you.

Comment: it didn't work I tried firebaseDb.database().ref(`users/ ${userName}`).once("value").then((snapshot.... but it didnot return the info about the user whose username is userName

Comment: @nour have you added that in the database? When an username is taken, you must add that node in the database. Also queries are case sensitive so I'd recommend storing those usernames in lowercase.

Comment: how and where do I add what your referring to

Comment: @nour where are you signing up the users? Can you share the code that you use to sign up users ?

Comment: I will edit the code and add the registration code

Comment: @nour I've updated my answer, that way you should add the new username to the database.

Comment: but I don't need an email, I only need a user name and password so I can't use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: and suppose I followed your solution and found the username, how will I check the password?

Comment: @nour I'd recommend using Firestore if you want to use username password custom auth. Although I'll still recommend firebase auth as it handles everything.

Answer (score 0):

you can check for all id's in the database if any fetch request from `http://<Server>/givenID/username` is the same as the given username. Same for the password.