# React js how to extract data from firebase's snapshot.val()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code and I need to extract the password from the userData object that appears in the console as follows:

-MeL7hm5pU3RGhvXnYlR: {name: "wed", password: "wed", userName: "wed"}

My code is

```
const Login = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    firebaseDb.child("authors").orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userName).once("value", snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const userData = snapshot.val();
            console.log(userData)

            if(userData.password !== password)
                window.alert("Username or Password are wrong!");
      
          else {
            history.push("/AuthorForm");
            localStorage.setItem("author-info", 

JSON.stringify(userName));
            }
  }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Adding to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68336407/13130697), this is NOT safe. People just need to try random names to fetch every user's password.

Comment: I already added conditioning to prevent duplicate usernames and its working, I just need to confirm the password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Using this way is not secure. Anyone making a login request will get the password of that username because you are doing client side validation.*

Apart from that, your object looks like:

```
{ 
  "-MeL7hm5pU3RGhvXnYlR": {
    name: "wed", 
    password: "wed", 
    userName: "wed"
  }
}
```

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to access the name and password fields.

```
const {name, password, userName} = Object.values(thatObjectAbove)[0]

console.log(name, password, userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Your code needs to handle the fact that it gets a list of results, typically by using Firebase's built-in `forEach` method:

```
firebaseDb.child("authors").orderByChild("userName").equalTo(userName).once("value", results => {
  if (results.exists()) {
    results.forEach((snapshot) => {
      const userData = snapshot.val();
      console.log(userData)

      if(userData.password !== password) {
            window.alert("Username or Password are wrong!");      
      }
      else {
        history.push("/AuthorForm");
        localStorage.setItem("author-info", 

        JSON.stringify(userName));
      }
    });
  }
});
```